# Blue Screen Of Death Only After Playing Counter Strike 1.6

Tags: windows-7, bsod, gaming

I have observing this weird behavior in my laptop from last 8-10 months that after playing Counter Strike 1.6 for 4th or 5th time, Blue Screen of Death Appears as soon as I close the game. Still not able to figure out what the exact reason is. I also play more heavy games like Dota 2, but that works fine. In between that time period I haven't played Counter Strike 1.6 for like 3 months and there was not a single Blue Screen Error in that period, so I am pretty sure that something related to this game is the cause. Need Help.

Blue Screen Error: [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ct1DXb7_2GQjJVSmxTMXZBdUk/view?usp=sharing)

And My Dump File from C:\Windows\Minidump is here:
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ct1DXb7_2GUlVxX2tFNkFiSnc/view?usp=sharing)

System Specification of my laptop:
Sony Vaio E-Series VPCEB46FG
OS- Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M480 @ 2.67GHz
Ram - 4GB
HDD - 500GB
Display Driver - ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Hmmm....what type of help do you need.  You obviously realize the problem is with Counter Strike...Isn't the logical path to contact the manufacturer/vendor of the software for support?

Comment: Might be video driver trouble. We can't really help you without the dump files for further diagnostics, so please post them on Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, or some other cloud storage service so we can analyze them.

Comment: @magicandre1981 and DragonLord - Links added.

Comment: @mdpc - that game works perfect for my friends but not for me.So there is some problem. I just need to figure it out. :)

Comment: @Ramhound - System Specifications Added. As soon as I close this  game(counter strike 1.6), Blue screen occurs. I dont know how to find drivers which were loaded at time of crash. Can you please help. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: @Ramhound - Sorry I dont know about this program and I even dont the location of Dump Files. Someone asked me to share and so I did. I used BlueScreen Viewer and find out the Problem is because of dxgmms1.sys. Can anyone help me from now onwards what to be done ?

Comment: @Ramhound: *"We need more information about your system before we can help. Can you tell us what your system specs are and what driver versions you're using? Information about the drivers loaded at the time of the crash can be helpful as well."*

Comment: @Gurpreet - I am aware you were not aware of `BlueScreenView` since you asked for more assistance.  Lets start with the basics.  Provide the relevant information from a `dxdiag` report indicating the display driver version.  You might also attempt to reinstall version of `Direct X 9` used by CS 1.6.  You should also verify if you have Windows fully updated.

Comment: WinDbg says crash is caused by a segfault (0xC000005 `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`) in `win32k.sys` at `HmgLockEx()`. Investigating further...

Comment: @Ramhound - Display Driver Version is 14.501.1003.0. I am trying updating everything as DragonLord Said. I will also try reinstalling `Direct X 9` if problem still persists. Will get back to u. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1):

#### A core system driver `win32k.sys` segfaulted in `HmgLockEx()`, resulting in a Stop 0x3B `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION` crash. This is typically caused by updating a driver without updating to the latest service pack.

- From your crash dump, WinDbg reports you are using Windows 7 build 7600, which means you are running Windows 7 without service packs installed.
- Update your system to the latest service pack, then update your video driver.

WinDbg output is as follows:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [E:\sysdebug\011515-53945-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*E:\sysdebug\debug-symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7600 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7600.17273.amd64fre.win7_gdr.130318-1532
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03a4e000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03c8ae70
Debug session time: Thu Jan 15 12:55:46.185 2015 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 3:11:04.715
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
...........................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
......
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 3B, {c0000005, fffff960000f6483, fffff880078d6070, 0}

Probably caused by : win32k.sys ( win32k!HmgLockEx+a3 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff960000f6483, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff880078d6070, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
win32k!HmgLockEx+a3
fffff960`000f6483 0fb7430c        movzx   eax,word ptr [rbx+0Ch]

CONTEXT:  fffff880078d6070 -- (.cxr 0xfffff880078d6070;r)
rax=fffff900c0200000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffa80064203b0
rdx=fffff900c0200000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=fffff900c0200000
rip=fffff960000f6483 rsp=fffff880078d6a40 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000001  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff880078d6aa8 r12=0000000003ce0200 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
win32k!HmgLockEx+0xa3:
fffff960`000f6483 0fb7430c        movzx   eax,word ptr [rbx+0Ch] ds:002b:00000000`0000000c=????
Last set context:
rax=fffff900c0200000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffa80064203b0
rdx=fffff900c0200000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=fffff900c0200000
rip=fffff960000f6483 rsp=fffff880078d6a40 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000001  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff880078d6aa8 r12=0000000003ce0200 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000001 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
win32k!HmgLockEx+0xa3:
fffff960`000f6483 0fb7430c        movzx   eax,word ptr [rbx+0Ch] ds:002b:00000000`0000000c=????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff960002b2620 to fffff960000f6483

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`078d6a40 fffff960`002b2620 : fffff900`c06026e0 00000000`00000001 00000000`10121300 fffff900`c0712cd0 : win32k!HmgLockEx+0xa3
fffff880`078d6ab0 fffff960`002b1b1e : fffff900`c06026e0 00000000`00000000 00001300`624d4653 00000000`0000001d : win32k!SFMLOGICALSURFACE::OwnsSurfaceCleanup+0x40
fffff880`078d6ae0 fffff960`002b2a23 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`10121300 fffff900`c06026e0 00000000`03ce0230 : win32k!SFMLOGICALSURFACE::DeInitialize+0x4e
fffff880`078d6b20 fffff960`0020f197 : 00000000`00000000 fffff900`c00bf010 fffff900`c06026e0 00000000`00000020 : win32k!bhLSurfDestroyLogicalSurfaceObject+0x4b
fffff880`078d6b60 fffff960`002306e8 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 fffff880`078d6ca0 00000000`00000000 : win32k!GreSfmCloseCompositorRef+0x10f
fffff880`078d6ba0 fffff800`03abcad3 : fffffa80`064203b0 00000000`03a7f930 000007fe`00000000 fffffa80`03dfa590 : win32k!NtGdiHLSurfSetInformation+0x1a8
fffff880`078d6c20 000007fe`ff824efa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`03a7f388 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x000007fe`ff824efa


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!HmgLockEx+a3
fffff960`000f6483 0fb7430c        movzx   eax,word ptr [rbx+0Ch]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!HmgLockEx+a3

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5130212e

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7600.17266

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff880078d6070 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_win32k!HmgLockEx+a3

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x3B_win32k!HmgLockEx+a3

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x3b_win32k!hmglockex+a3

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {8f81bb6a-de67-bc4d-99db-3f117a68551c}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: I am done with updating windows to latest service pack(Took lot of time). I tried updating my Graphics Driver but it failed. I am trying again(uninstall and again install). I will get back to you if problem still persist after installation. Thanks a lot!