# BSOD when PC is unattended

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I frequently get a BSOD if I leave my computer unattended for a period of time.

SOmetimes it happens after a few minutes, sometimes after an hour.

I am sure this is something to do with either USB ports or the WiFi connector. I have changed the WiFi connection from a PCI card to a USB dongle but this did not fix the problem.

Disconnecting all USB devices seems to prolong the problem but not entirely fix the problem.
Below is the error info upon restart:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2057

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   3b
  BCP1: 00000000C0000005
  BCP2: FFFFF800030D072C
  BCP3: FFFFF880031FE6B0
  BCP4: 0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\021615-13322-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Jamie\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-335823-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

The WER-335823-0.sysdata.xml] can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/2jxj72V1)

I have the dmp file if anyone has any suggestions and can help me further. This is becoming increasingly frustrating.

Comment: Bad driver, bad memory, other hardware isssue (psu, motherboard, video card)... too many possible causes.

Comment: Does event viewer shed any information. Any way, download BlueScreenView  and see what it says about the dump file

Comment: Why do you suspect USB devices and Wi-Fi adapters? Are your drivers up to date? Load the .dmp into BlueScreenView and see what it says.

Comment: Stop 3B is often (almost always) video card drivers (or a faulty video card). Try updating your video card drivers to the latest version.

Comment: Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is right.  I had a similar problem when I first built my new machine.  I couldn't shutdown it down without it crashing, but I could reset it, ended up being a display driver.  The device couldn't or wouldn't respond to the shutdown routine and eventually Windows would just crash.  This also presented a problem with sleep mode.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/864978/blue-screen-of-death-only-after-playing-counter-strike-1-6/865290#865290

Comment: **gronostaj:** I suspected USB devices due to the fact that removing them prolonged the duration the PC would "stay alive"

Comment: **Technie007/Ramhound**, I will try updating drivers on my system but as I am not using an external video card and am pretty sure my motherboard drivers are up-to-date, I'm not sure this will help. I will certainly try though.

I think the solution I gave below sounds interesting though!

Comment: upload this file to OneDrive/Dropbox and post a link here:  **C:\Windows\Minidump\021615-13322-01.dmp**

Comment: @JamieReid you must have some kind of video card. If it's a relatively new machine then it's probably integrated in your CPU, not motherboard.

Comment: @gronostaj absolutely, it is an integrated Intel GPU chip. I have updated the drivers. The original BSOD is gone. I'now onto a new BSOD related to HAL.dll.

The original BSOD was indeed cured by my solution below. The new BSOD has a completely different error code (0x00000124).

Trying to get the drivers updated correctly, but seem to keep getting some kind of mismatch from the Intel site and the ASUS site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible this is related to hibernation on Windows 7 and my SSD.

Google brings up multiple results to BSODs on that. A colleague just informed me of this.

http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/264064-frequent-bsod-hibernation-windows-7-x64-ssd.html´
http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/bsod-on-hibernate-caused-by-ssd.619680/

Comment: This has not resolved the problem **but** this has saved ver needed 16gb of needed spaced by removing paging file and hibernation file. So it was a useful exercise.

Comment: Possibly this has resolved the problem, the BSOD seen last night was completely different and seems related to temporary files. I have moved these to a new drives as a part of improving SSD performance.
I am going to move my work (I am a freelancer programmer) to another PC and leave this PC alone for a full day. If it doesn't BSOD for a full day, I think that this was the solution!

Fingers crossed, if it was. Sorry for raising the question!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some files corrupted in your computer so open command prompt with administrative rights and type SFC /Scannow and hit enter, it will fix your problems else post here with update.

Comment: It found some problems but did not resolve the BSOD.